# What jS to change button background colour on Google Tag Manager?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'd like to change the background of a button with the use of Google Tag Manager. But I don't know the jS code to do it. I tried the lines below but it doesn't change anything:

```html
<style>
  a.icon-btn-green {
    background-color: #d29f13
  }
 </style>
```

Comment: Those lines of code are just styling. They can't change on their own.

Comment: And do you know how I can do the change?

Comment: I do, but this is not a website where people code FOR you. Changing element styling using javascript is very easy and easily found on Google. [JavaScript HTML DOM - Changing CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp) for example. I have no knowledge about Google Tag manager, but this is the way to do it using Javascript.

Comment: Yes, I checked the page but I only managed to change the text of my button. The background seems really impossible to change.

Comment: document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"; changes the background of the body. So changing the background color of something is not impossible.